# iOS 8.2 CoreBluetooth - CentralManager not calling delegate didDiscoverPeripherals

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

Since upgrading to iOS 8.2 I seem to be having trouble with CoreBluetooth. I had a previous application working that ran a CBCentralManager subclass to scan for UUIDs I wanted. Now, I'm unable to get a delegate callback to `didDiscoverPeripherals`.

I've verified that the peripherals are broadcasting correctly via LightBlue. I've verified that the CentralManager state is powered on before calling scan. I tried scanning both with my UUID and also with nil. Again, I had this code working for weeks before upgrading. Has anyone else experienced this or have any idea what could be going on?

EDIT - added code CBCentralManager subclass code

```
@implementation CentralManager

-(id) initWithDelegate:(id<CBCentralManagerDelegate>)delegate queue:(dispatch_queue_t)queue {
    self = [super initWithDelegate:delegate
                             queue:queue
                           options:nil];
    _items = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    _discoveredPeripherals = [NSMutableArray new];
    _app = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    return self;
}

-(void) startScan {
    if (!_isScanning && self.state == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn && _app.loggedIn) {
        [self scanForPeripheralsWithServices:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:APP_SERVICE_UUID]] options:nil];
        _isScanning = YES;
        NSLog(@"Scanning started");
    }
}

-(void) stopScan {
    [super stopScan];
    _isScanning = NO;
    NSLog(@"Scanning stopped");
}
```

In AppDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
if (!_centralManager) {
    _centralQueue = dispatch_queue_create("centralQueue", nil);
    _centralManager = [[CentralManager alloc]initWithDelegate:self queue:_centralQueue];
}
    [_peripheralManager beginAdvertising];
    [_centralManager startScan];
}

- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central {
    if (central.state == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        [_centralManager startScan];
    }
}
```

`startScan` is called twice depending on if user is logged in or `centralManager` is powered on first. I basically treat `peripheralManager` identically and that works (verified by Light Blue).

Comment: Are you storing a reference to your `CBCentralManager` in a property?  Can you show the code where you setup your central and scan for peripherals?

Comment: I added some relevant code above. Yes, I store my `CBCentralManager` subclass ref in an `AppDelegate` property.

Comment: Have you tried turning your device off & on again?  I have had issues where Bluetooth doesn't co-operate for no apparent reason and turning off & on again fixes it

Comment: I don't think this is your problem, but subclassing CBCentralManager and getting it to hold a reference to your app delegate and putting application code in it is icky.  Also try to get into the habit of using `self.property` instead of `_property` unless you explicitly want to bypass the setter/getter

Comment: I have witnessed situations where restarting the device fixed this type of issue. I even factory-reset one of my test devices. However, that didn't help this time. Also - I have been using a weak reference to `_app` throughout my application files (i.e. subclasses, controllers) as a convenience for the AppDelegate. Can this lead to unexpected behavior for any reason?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue has to do with subclassing `CBCentralManager`. Maybe because of these recent [changes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS82APIDiffs/frameworks/CoreBluetooth.html) in iOS 8.2, because it worked fine before. A quick fix is to add an ivar `manager` in the subclass and initialize a `CBCentralManager`. Then call `scan` on that manager. While this is probably not a clean approach, it highlights the issue.

Comment: @Paulw11 if you care to post an answer to shed some light on what's going on here (i.e. why subclassing `CBCentralManager` doesn't work the way I originally had it), I could mark it as accepted answer.